# Can not detect mousePress event when touch in Windows 7

Tags: qt

Sample:

```
Label::Label(QLabel *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
    this->show();
    this->resize(200, 200);
}

void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    this->resize(300, 300);
}
```

Expected result： when i press label by touching, the label will become bigger.

Actual result： when i release or move my finger, it become bigger.

Its looks like the mousePressEvent is not detected.

BTW QML also have same problem for `MouseArea` `onPressed`

Thanks for answering, i tried to add this:

```
bool Label::event(QEvent *e)
{
    if(e->type() == QEvent::TouchBegin)
    qDebug() << "TouchBegin";
    if(e->type() == QEvent::TouchCancel)
    qDebug() << "TouchCancel";
    if(e->type() == QEvent::TouchEnd)
    qDebug() << "TouchEnd";
    if(e->type() == QEvent::TouchUpdate)
    qDebug() << "TouchUpdate";
    return e->isAccepted();
}
```

But the TouchBegin event still not be detected when i pressed.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html

Comment: I am not sure for windows, but on linux I was trying to determine the difference between "touch" events and actual "mouse" events. It may be that when you put your finger on the screen you get one of the following:
`QEvent::TouchBegin, QEvent::TouchUpdate, QEvent::TouchEnd` It is worth trying these out if windows distinguishes between real touch events and mouse events. But as I say, I am not sure for windows.

Comment: An active touch event is not a mouse event yet. What you see is correct behavior. You need to handle touch events explicitly.

Comment: I tried, Looks like this BUG only occur in Windows.